# onCreate() and onDestroy() NOT symmetric?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, resources, oncreate, ondestroy

I am learning android and came up with what I think as a weird observation:

based on the diagram and description on https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
It seems the two callbacks onCreate and onDestroy are not symmetric.

It seems that when an app loses its focus or be put to the background, the system could kill the app without calling onDestroy. Later on, when the app is up again, onCreate is called.

I tried to test this, but couldn't figure out how to simulate the situation when the system would kill the app because of memory issues. I tried to open a lot of apps on my phone, the test app was never killed :)

Let's say it does happen in some cases. Does that mean you could have onCreate be called more than onDestroy, which could potentially cause memory leaks if you happen to acquire resources in onCreate and release the onDestroy? If my observation is true, any best practices out there to solve the resource release issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation can really explain this better](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy()).

However, in short, `onDestroy()` will be called if an `Activity` is ended with `finish()` or Android needs the resources that your app is using.

I will typically not use `onDestroy()` to manage resources. In fact, I do not think I have ever used `onDestroy()` in any app I have written.

I will use `onPause()` to ensure that resources are gone in a timely fashion. You will only really need to do that for resources that are registered (like `BroadcastReceiver`). Stopping repeating `Handler` messages. Things like that.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but i think there is a way to simulate system kill app with adb command

https://possiblemobile.com/2017/10/android-testing-app-killed-background/

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to test this, but couldn't figure out how to simulate the situation when the system would kill the app because of memory issues.

Just use Settings->Developer options->Dont't keep activities mode to get onDestroy all the time. Also use Background process limit at the same menu.

Loose call of onDestroy is extreme situation. System calls onDestroy every time activity destroyed, even in not enough memory case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. With tips from @Igor, I was able to test and prove the points mentioned by @Knossos: OnDestroy is called as soon as the app loses the focus. Which means onCreate and onDestroy are still symmetric, as far as I am aware. Which also means the diagram on the android documentation site (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) needs a little improvement.

Thanks again for everyone's input. As to the best practices for resource management, now that I think more of it, it deserves a whole lot of in-depth discussions, as many factors could contribute to the complexity: the types of resources, the system overhead of getting and releasing them, etc...